# Using a different account for writing reviews on Play Store

Tags: google-play-store, google

I'm not sure if this is the correct site to ask this, but when I download an app from the Play Store, I use a different account for writing a review after using the app. I wanted to ask if what I'm doing is allowed or not, and if it's not, then I'll just stop writing reviews from another account. I'm feeling kind of bad thinking what I'm doing might be wrong. I know this question is a bit weird, but I just wanted to ask. Thanks.

Comment: The reason i would use a different account is because i would not want my name displayed

Answer (score 1):

Google Play [write a review](https://support.google.com/googleplay/answer/4346705?co=GENIE.Platform%3DAndroid&hl=en) does not say that your review account has to be the same as the account on the phone. You can have [multiple accounts](https://support.google.com/googleplay/answer/2521798#switch) on your device.

So I would conclude what you are doing isn't wrong, but I see no advantages of doing so. On the contrary, it may cause confusion. Let's say a developer responded to your review saying that a paid app isn't working and asks you for app logs, they would see a different account

Comment: You are correct, it would cause a lot of confusion. I have decided to start using just one account for everything. As for the reason, I'm a bit embarrassed to share it, hope you understand. Anyway, thanks for replying :)